# JPA: persisting entity with composite primary key

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I have two tables in database, A and B. Table B has an id composed of two fields. One of them is a foreign key to A. Id of A is automatically generated on insert by a sequence.

```
A:
    ID (PK)
    (*other fields*)

B:
    SOME_FIELD (PK)
    A_ID (PK, FK to A)
```

I have mapped the two tables in JPA (Hibernate) following [JPA specification](http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/jcp/persistence-2.0-fr-eval-oth-JSpec/persistence-2_0-final-spec.pdf), in this way:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "A")
public class A implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "A_SEQ", sequenceName = "A_SEQ")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "A_SEQ")
    @Column(name = "ID")
    private Long id;
  (...)
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "B")
public class B implements Serializable {
    @EmbeddedId
    @AttributeOverride(name = "someField", column = @Column(name = SOME_FIELD))
    private BPK pk;

    @MapsId("aId")
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "A_ID")
    private A a;
  (...)
}

@Embeddable
public class BPK implements Serializable {
    private Long aId;
    private String someField;

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        (...)
    }

    @Override
    public boolean hashCode() {
        (...)
    }

    (...)
}
```

The problem is that when I try to save an B object calling entityManager.persist(b), where b.a is set to an A object, which exists already in database, I get an exception:

```
javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.PersistentObjectException: detached entity passed to persist: package.name.A
```

I don't know why this happens. I'm trying to save object of class B, not A. Is my entity class wrong? Or maybe I shouldn't use persist here?

Comment: You need to implement `Serializable` in your entity class.

Comment: I implement this. I didn't copy the "implements" part because I implement more interfaces and didn't want to include unnecessary parts in my code. Updated the question with "implements Serializable".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It could be that the entity A is no longer being held by entity manager. Have you tried setting B.a with a "fresh" instance of A?

```
b.setA(get(b.a));
entityManager.persist(b);
```

The `get(b.a)` method can be whatever you usually use to find entity A from your datasource e.g. `entityManager.getReference(A.class, a.id);`

Comment: Thank you, it helps. But I don't understand why it doesn't work without such "refresh". For other entities, where foreign key is present, but not included in composite primary key, I simply call entityManager.persist and it works. Does it matter, that foreign key is a part of primary key in this case?

Comment: Composite primary keys are a strange beast - I've struggled with them in the past. To be honest, because of this I tend to stick to a simple id for the primary key and then make the composite a foreign key.

Comment: I think it is something to do with the fact that you are creating two entities (B and BPK) and A is part of both of those entities. Because A (as part of the primary key) is critical to persistence, JPA insists on it being "fresh".

Comment: Within the scope of the entity manager, any changes to A are cached and Hibernate knows if it must be first created or updated. If you are persisting B via a `@Remote` interface (and probably `@Local` too - I can't quite remember) then A has been detached from the entity manager and Hibernate doesn't know if A has already been changed.

Comment: It's madness, but there's a method to this madness :P

Comment: "Because A (as part of the primary key) is critical to persistence, JPA insists on it being "fresh"" - is this your guess or you have found something like this in specification? If it's true, the embeddedId, mapsId etc. seem useless to me... I have generic methods for save, update and delete, and it would be stupid if I had to refresh foreign keys before this operations...

Comment: The JPA documentation is not the greatest so if I can't find what I'm looking for I also check the hibernate docs (which usually points out if something is non-JPA standard). Other than that I fall back on SO and google...

Comment: (http://www.objectdb.com/java/jpa/persistence/detach) gives a nice summary of the cause of your problem. The entity manager knows nothing about a detached instance of A. It doesn't know if it exists in the database or if it has been changed and needs updating before using it to persist your B entity.

Comment: The advantage of using getReference(...) is that in situations where you know that entity A exists and has not been modified, it retrieves the bare minimum required to attach the entity to the entity manager (no eager loading etc.).